# Launch Screen Storyboard's Image Disappears

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, launch-screen

I recently changed from launch images to a launch screen storyboard.  I debugged the app on my phone, and everything looked great.  I made some changes on other areas of the app's code, updated the build number, and installed the new version, but now the image on that storyboard is missing, and just shows as black.  Any ideas as to why the image would disappear when I've made no changes at all to that storyboard?  The image is still in the project, and I checked the source code for the storyboard, and it is correctly typed in there as well.  All works on simulator.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same thing. Try to remove the ".png" extensions on the images in the interface designer. This made them disappear in the designer, but they did appear in the app!